# Android Chromium Scroll Events Capturing

Tags: android, chromium

I am trying to understand Chromium source code for Android. I would like to modify the Chromium and get an event whenever the user scrolls the web page.

Is there some central class or piece of code which controls all these events?

I found the `GestureEventFilter` and the `GestureHandler` interface, but i am not sure whether this is the piece of code controlling all the events.

It would be really helpful if you could give me some idea.

Comment: If you are not sure then try setting a breakpoint and debug your code. If it was for Windows, I would have helped

Comment: Well, the problem is, that it is probably somewhere in C++ code. The debuging is thus not really possible.